# Notification when a checkbox in a JTable is checked

Tags: java, jtable, jcheckbox

I've searched for this for quite a while and haven't found a clear example anywhere.  I'm a Java newbee using NetBeans.  I have a boolean value in the first column of a JTable (called "Enabled") and I have some plugin code that I need to call to see if it has the settings it needs in order to be enabled, and if not, display a message box and prevent Enabled from being checked.

All I really need is for a function to be called when the checkbox is checked and I can take it from there.  Does anyone have an example of how to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Harry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a [`TableModelListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html), as discussed in [*Listening for Data Changes*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange). Alternatively, you can use a [custom editor](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table), as discussed in [*Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and the following section.

Comment: +1, the TableModelListener is the way to go when you want to know when a value in the model has been changed.

Comment: Ah, that's the stuff!  Thanks for your help!  Now I just have to clean up from all my failed attempts that didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

> All I really need is for a function to
>   be called when the checkbox is checked

When the checkbox is checked then the value will be changed in the model, which is probably not what your want. I would think you want to prevent the checking of the checkbox in the first place.

The way to prevent a cell from being editable is to override the isCellEditable(...) method of JTable. By overriding this method you can dynamically determine if the cell should be editable or not.

```
JTable table = new JTable( ... )
{
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
    {
        int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

        if (modelColumn == yourBooleanColumn)
            return isTheBooleanForThisRowEditable(row);
        else
            return super.isCellEditable(row, column);
    }
};
```

And a fancier approach would be to create a custom renderer so that the check box looks "disabled" even before the user attempts to click on the cell. See the link provided by trashgod on renderers.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating the required index transformation. An added benefit of the custom renderer is being able to specify a tool tip.